# Find Transformation Matrix with constraint

Tags: linear-algebra

I have two sets of 3d points, and I have to find the best transformation matrix between the two sets. This I can do, and I do it via an SVD algorithm.

However, I'd like to add a constraint to this transformation. For example, I'd like one specific point of the first set to correspond exactly to a specific point of the second set.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thinking about this, probably this question doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

That means that one of the row of the matrix will be $(0,0,\cdots,1,\cdots,0)$.
Permutate the points so as to bring the $1$ on the upper corner, and proceed as usual with the $n-1$ matrix. Finally do a back-permutation.